# Search vector<char> buffer for string

Tags: c++, regex

I want to search for password strings using regex in an `std::vector<char>` buffer filled from `ReadProcessMemory()`. `std::search()` could be used to search for a specific pattern, but I want to use regex to find all possible values. The function `find_all()` would then return to me the address of a corresponding regex match string.

`cregex_iterator` cannot use my `buf_start` and `buf_end` iterators:

> "initializer list" cannot be converted into "std::cregex_iterator"

Is there another function I can use for the regex search, or maybe chain with `std::search()`?

My code looks like this:

```cpp
template <class outIter>
void find_locs(HANDLE process, std::string const& pattern, outIter output) {

    unsigned char* p = NULL;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;

    for (p = NULL;
        VirtualQueryEx(process, p, &info, sizeof(info)) == sizeof(info);
        p += info.RegionSize)
    {
        std::vector<char> buffer;
        std::vector<char>::iterator pos;

        if (info.State == MEM_COMMIT &&
            (info.Type == MEM_MAPPED || info.Type == MEM_PRIVATE))
        {
            SIZE_T bytes_read;
            buffer.resize(info.RegionSize);
            ReadProcessMemory(process, p, &buffer[0], info.RegionSize, &bytes_read);
            buffer.resize(bytes_read);
            find_all(p, buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), pattern.begin(), pattern.end(), output);
        }
    }
}

template <class InIter1, class InIter2, class OutIter>
void find_all(unsigned char* base, InIter1 buf_start, InIter1 buf_end, InIter2 pat_start, InIter2 pat_end, OutIter res) {
    // password regex string
    std::regex r("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,10}$");
    InIter1 pos = buf_start;
    //This doenst work
    for (cregex_iterator i = cregex_iterator(buf_start, buf_end, r);
        i != cregex_iterator();
        ++i)
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        std::cout << m.str() << '\n';
        *res++ = base + (pos - buf_start);
        ++pos;
    }

 /*
    for (InIter1 pos = buf_start; buf_end != (pos = std::search(pos, buf_end, pat_start, pat_end));++pos)
    {
        *res++ = base + (pos - buf_start);

    } */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of `cregex_iterator`, it's constructor expects raw `const char*` pointers for its input iterators:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator

> ```
> template<
>     class BidirIt,
>     class CharT = typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::value_type,
>     class Traits = std::regex_traits<CharT>
> > class regex_iterator
> ```
>
> | Type | Definition |
> | --- | --- |
> | `cregex_iterator` | `regex_iterator<const char*>` |

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator/regex_iterator

> ```
> regex_iterator( BidirIt a, BidirIt b,
>                 const regex_type& re,
>                 std::regex_constants::match_flag_type m =
>                     std::regex_constants::match_default );
> ```

However, `vector` iterators are not required to be (and usually are not) implemented as raw pointers, hence your error.

Try using `buffer.data()` instead to get raw pointers that you can use as iterators into the `vector`'s data, eg:

```
find_all(..., buffer.data(), buffer.data() + buffer.size(), ...);
```

---

On a side note, `++pos` in your search loop will advance `pos` by only 1 byte at a time, but you are searching for strings, so you should be advancing `pos` by the byte size of the current match instead.  For that matter, you probably shouldn't even be using `pos` at all, you should instead be using the [`position`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/position) that is reported by the current match.